# Garbage session files and cookie problem in the session in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-10

Previously, I was keeping sessions on **file** in my Laravel project. But since there were too many session files, I decided to keep the session in **cookies**. While the session is kept in cookies, it is also kept in the `storage/framework/sessions` file. Since my hosting **iNode** limit is **249,000**, my server keeps getting **500 errors**.
How can I permanently delete or disable these session files?

**Kind regards.**

Comment: Are you talking about _new_ session files, that were created _after_ you switched to the `cookie` driver? Or are you just looking at older files from before, that simply never got garbage collected correctly (perhaps _because_ you switched to cookies)?

Comment: Even though I delete the session file, when I change it to cookie, new session files are created. They are occuring again and again. @CBroe